# What are the names of common MMC snapins?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows

I know that if I type into the run dialog

```
eventvwr
```

Then the event viewer appears, and if I type in

```
intemgr
```

Then the internet information systems mmc snap in appears.  Are there also shortcuts to other common mmc snapins? (for example the Users mmc snap in)

Answer (score 3):

`dir c:\windows\*.msc /s /b /p`

- adsiedit.msc
- azman.msc
- certmgr.msc
- certsrv.msc
- certtmpl.msc
- comexp.msc
- compmgmt.msc
- devmgmt.msc
- dhcpmgmt.msc
- diskmgmt.msc
- dnsmgmt.msc
- domain.msc
- dsa.msc **Active Directory Users**
- dssite.msc
- eventvwr.msc
- fsmgmt.msc
- gpedit.msc
- gpmc.msc
- gpme.msc
- gptedit.msc
- lusrmgr.msc **Local Users**
- NAPCLCFG.MSC
- perfmon.msc
- pkiview.msc
- printmanagement.msc
- rsop.msc
- secpol.msc
- ServerManager.msc
- services.msc
- SQLServerManager.msc
- SQLServerManager10.msc
- taskschd.msc
- tpm.msc
- tsadmin.msc
- tsmmc.msc
- WF.msc
- WmiMgmt.msc
- adsiedit.msc
- azman.msc
- certmgr.msc
- certsrv.msc
- certtmpl.msc
- comexp.msc
- compmgmt.msc
- devmgmt.msc
- dhcpmgmt.msc
- diskmgmt.msc
- dnsmgmt.msc
- domain.msc
- dsa.msc
- dssite.msc
- eventvwr.msc
- fsmgmt.msc
- gpedit.msc
- gpmc.msc
- gpme.msc
- gptedit.msc
- lusrmgr.msc
- NAPCLCFG.MSC
- perfmon.msc
- pkiview.msc
- printmanagement.msc
- rsop.msc
- secpol.msc
- ServerManager.msc
- services.msc
- taskschd.msc
- tpm.msc
- tsadmin.msc
- tsmmc.msc
- WF.msc
- WmiMgmt.msc
- iis.msc
- iis6.msc

YMMV as I have the remote administration tools installed, along with things like SQL Server etc

Comment: Maybe you should remove duplicates and state for every entry, what the mmc snapin "project" is about

Comment: @Scoregraphic - Edited per your suggestions...